# SQL Alchemy update row based on optional fields from rest api

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How to elegantly update the DB rows for selected fields that are optional from rest endpoint using the sqlalchemy.

Assume there is a user moel :

```
class User(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'user'
        id = Column(u'id', Integer(), primary_key=True)
        name = Column(u'name', String(50),nullable = False)
        address = Column(u'adress', String(50))
        notes = Column(u'notes', String(50))
```

Example: I have an API that accepts optional parameters to update user data:

Case 1:

```
  {"id":1,
   "name":"nameone",
   "address":"one address"
}
```

Case 2: here address is optional

```
{  "id":1,
   "name":"name-1",
   "notes":"test notes"
}
```

I can update the row using SQLalchemy if the fields are known

For Case 1 :

```
User.update().where(User.id == id).values(name="nameone",address="one address")
```

For Case 2 :

```
User.update().where(User.id == id).values(name="name-1",notes="test notes")
```

Is there any elegant way to do this instead of writing cases for each case scenario using sqlalchemy ORM?

Comment: You already have the keywords so there shouldn't be any further work

Comment: I was looking to see if there is an elegant way to do instead of writing cases for each case scenario.

Comment: I added an answer below. You could use it in a for loop

Comment: Assuming the data is validated--  `User.query.get(data['id']).update(data)`

Answer (score 1):

Use Python to do your logic

```
data = {  "id":1,
   "name":"name-1",
   "notes":"test notes"
}

user = User.query.filter(User.id == data['id']).first()

for attr, val in data.items():
    if not attr == 'id':
        setattr(user, attr, val)
```

Comment: is it possible to do this in a single database call instead of two calls one is to fetch row and another call to update it?

Comment: It might be possible, but I don't know of a way myself. I don't know your application, but beware of premature optimization. You can always come back to this part of your code if it becomes a problem but until then it might be more efficient for you to leave it as two calls.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, it sound like you are asking how to write only one 'update' statement for different combinations of fields.

An elegant way is to use a dictionary variable in the `values` parameter.

For example:

```
if case1:
    values_dict = {"id":1, "name":"nameone", "address":"one address"}
else:
    values_dict = {"id":1, "name":"name-1", "notes":"test notes"}

User.update().where(User.id == id).values(values_dict)
```

Depending on how your API returns the data you may or may not need use the case logic in this example.

See also https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.update

> "**values** – Optional dictionary which specifies the SET conditions of
> the UPDATE."